# ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT for Launching Google

Tags: windows, browser, internet-connection

My PC is connecting the internet through Mobile.
While launching Google,am getting "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT " some time "NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID" error(Tried with chrome,firefox,IE).But site can reach from mobile.Could you please help on this ? Kindly let me know if any log require for verification.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear your browser data such as cookies, app data, cache files etc

Comment: Tried with remove cookies and etc in chrome browser alone.but no luck.Do want me to do same thing for other browser?

Comment: next try to flush/renew DNS. open cmd and type "ipconfig /flushdns

Comment: or here you can read many way to resolved that trouble. http://www.incrediblelab.com/connection-timed-out-error-fixed/

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, now issue resolved.Root cause is "Google and facebook site were added in System32 > Drivers > etc>host.txt file. (Ref link: http://www.incrediblelab.com/connection-timed-out-error-fixed/).now i removed and its works fine

Comment: Hi,Ahmed,still issue persisting if restart the system.could you please help me to give permanent solution.